# C# hide a row in datagridviewer depending on the user's role that has logged into the application

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms, datagridview, permissions

Greetings i have a feature i want to add to my program which is hiding and displaying rows depending on the user role that logged onto the application

for example
(all user data are in MySql database)

if a person with the "Sales" role logged into the application He will not see the quantity row in the datagridviewer

if a person with the "Warehouse Manager" role logged into the application he can see everything in the datagridviewer

but unfortunately i dont know the correct code to user here

my thought the code will be put in form load but iam missing the code it self

Thank you.

Comment: It would probably be better to use different sql queries based on user roles.  Instead of hiding rows (I suspect columns), you only grab the relevant data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good solution would be to manually populate the datagridview and check the role of users at the same time. While populating the datagridview, check if the logged-in user is in "Sales", skip this line of code:
DataGridView.Rows.Add(...).

note: For large amount of records a better solution would be to filter data based on the roles, in SQL query level.